# google maps distance matrix js api vs web call

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am using google maps distance matrix with two methods.
The first one is via javascript:

```
service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins         : [origin],
    destinations    : s[0],
    travelMode      : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem      : google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways   : false,
    avoidTolls      : false,
    drivingOptions  : { 
        departureTime   : new Date(),
        trafficModel    : google.maps.TrafficModel.BEST_GUESS 
    }
}, function(response, status) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

The second one is via php

```
function GetDrivingDistance($origins, $d_lat, $d_lon){
    $url  = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json";
    $url .= "?origins=".$origins;
    $url .= "&destinations=".$d_lat.",".$d_lon;
    $url .= "&mode=driving";
    $url .= "&departure_time=" . strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $url .= "&traffic_model=best_guess";
    $url .= "&language=en";
    $url .= "&key=" . GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY_DIS_MATRIX;
    // echo $url;
    $routes=json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
    return $routes;
}
```

When I run both codes simultaneously I get the results without any errors. What is confuse me is that the results are not the same!!!

I tried to compare the results with google maps (https://www.google.com/maps) and I concluded that the results from google maps were exactly the same with the code run with PHP.

Does anyone know why is this happening? The parameters are the same in both cases so I was waiting to get the same output.

e.g. 
PHP output:

```
php find_nearest.php 37.9911865,23.7547297

Array
(
    [destination_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Geor. Kedrinou 46, Athina 115 22, Greece
        )

[origin_addresses] => Array
    (
        [0] => Posidonos, Limni 340 05, Greece
        [1] => A/D PAThE 53-65, Ag. Ioannis Rentis 182 33, Greece
    )

[rows] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [elements] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [distance] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 155 km
                                        [value] => 154939
                                    )

                                [duration] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 2 hours 31 mins
                                        [value] => 9089
                                    )

                                [duration_in_traffic] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 2 hours 34 mins
                                        [value] => 9262
                                    )

                                [status] => OK
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [elements] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [distance] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 14.1 km
                                        [value] => 14103
                                    )

                                [duration] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 28 mins
                                        [value] => 1650
                                    )

                                [duration_in_traffic] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 30 mins
                                        [value] => 1799
                                    )

                                [status] => OK
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[status] => OK
```

)

javascript result:

```
/**/_xdc_._s0qz6t && _xdc_._s0qz6t( {
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "A/D PAThE 53-65, Ag. Ioannis Rentis 182 33, Greece",
      "Posidonos, Limni 340 05, Greece"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Georgiou Kedrinou 46, Athens 115 22, Greece" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "11,2 km",
                  "value" : 11204
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "24 mins",
                  "value" : 1449
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "27 mins",
                  "value" : 1636
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "156 km",
                  "value" : 155859
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 32 mins",
                  "value" : 9097
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 33 mins",
                  "value" : 9164
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
 )
```

Comment: The two requests are different.  You have the origin and destination arrays reversed.